# Go to next input field at maxLength?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

I have a form in Vue that has some combined inputs for styling reasons for a phone number input.

My problem is that the user has to hit tab in order to go to the next input field of the phone number.

Is there a way to check for the max length of the current and input and when that is met go to the next input?

```js
<div class="combined-input combined-input--phone" :class="{'error--input': phoneInvalid('patientInformation')}">
  <div class="open-parenthesis"></div>

  <input type="text" id="phoneArea" maxlength="3" @blur="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.$touch()" v-model.trim="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.area.$model">

  <div class="close-parenthesis"></div>

  <input type="text" id="phoneA" maxlength="3" @blur="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.$touch()" v-model.trim="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.a.$model">

  <div class="dash"></div>

  <input type="text" id="phoneB" maxlength="4" @blur="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.$touch()" v-model.trim="$v.formData.patientInformation.phone.b.$model">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is not recommended UX-wise but here is an example on how you can achieve it: https://codesandbox.io/s/move-to-next-input-on-condition-103b5?file=/src/App.vue

The main part of useful code is

```js
focusNextOncePopulated(event, max) {
  if (event.target.value.length === max) {
    const nextElement = this.$refs?.[`input-${Number(event.target.dataset.index) +1}`]
    if (nextElement) nextElement.focus()
  }
},
```

Explanation: each time you input a char, you check if the length of the field reached the maximum you've set on a particular input. If it is and there is a similar input as a sibling, you focus it.
Adding a [`debounce`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) of a few milliseconds would be nice too, performance-wise.

EDIT: to prevent any issues of trying to find the correct next `input` in the DOM, we setup some refs on each of the inputs (recommended way in Vue to select some DOM elements). Then, when we have reached the `max`, we increment our current's input `data-index` by one, which enables us to go to the next input.

PS: `?.` syntax is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), it prevents ugly code and allows to avoid an error if there is no next `input` once `max` is reached.

PS: Not sure if there is a way to directly get the `$refs` of an element on it's `@input` event but if there is, I didn't found out how to do it.

Comment: aaa nice! of course my nextSibling is the div close parenthesis or div dash...lol....thanks for advice though!

Comment: You need to setup a selector for the next input. Just updated my answer on a possible way to do it. It's a bit more verbose but allows to go back to a previous field and to have the next focused again, rather than the last we left of. If you want later's behavior, setting up a state in `data` and incrementing it all the way could be a solution.